# AngularJS: Conditional ng-class with several matches for one option.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-class

I have following snippet:

```
<span class="label"
              ng-class="{
              'label-success': resp.level == 'A1',
              'label-success': resp.level == 'A2',
              'label-warning': resp.level == 'B1',
              'label-warning': resp.level == 'B2',
              'label-danger': resp.level == 'C1',
              'label-danger': resp.level == 'C2',
              'label-default': resp.level == 'This word was not found',
              'label-default': resp.level == 'The word level is not known'}">{[{resp.level}]}</span>
```

It doesn't work, seems because of several matches for the same option.
This is work fine:

```
<span class="label"
              ng-class="{
              'label-success': resp.level == 'A1',
              'label-warning': resp.level == 'B1',
              'label-danger': resp.level == 'C1',
              'label-default': resp.level == 'The word level is not known'}">{[{resp.level}]}</span>
```

**Questions:**

- What is the reason?
- How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is not working because we are making object having duplicate key which is not allowed use

```
<span class="label"
          ng-class="{
          'label-success': (resp.level == 'A1' ||resp.level == 'A2'),

          'label-warning': (resp.level == 'B1' ||resp.level == 'B2'),

          'label-danger': (resp.level == 'C1' ||resp.level == 'c2'),

          'label-default': (resp.level == 'This word was not found' ||resp.level == 'The word level is not known')
          }">{[{resp.level}]}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can OR your conditions:

```
<span class="label"
          ng-class="{
          'label-success': resp.level === 'A1' || resp.level == 'A2',
          'label-warning': resp.level === 'B1' || resp.level == 'B2',
          'label-danger': resp.level === 'C1' || resp.level == 'C2',
          'label-default': resp.level === 'This word was not found' || resp.level === 'The word level is not known'}">{[{resp.level}]}</span>
```

or check just the first letter

```
<span class="label"
          ng-class="{
          'label-success': resp.level[0] === 'A',
          'label-warning': resp.level[0] === 'B',
          'label-danger': resp.level[0] === 'C',
          'label-default': resp.level[0] === 'T'}">{[{resp.level}]}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) object definition:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
>      surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
>      string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
>      from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
>      name.  The names within an object **SHOULD** be unique.

In your case ng-class attribute argument is object so it can't have duplicate names. But you can you logical 'or' operator like this:

```
ng-class={'active': someVal === 1 || someVal === 2}
```